# Playing simply song in my php code

Tags: php, media-player

There is what i've done

```
echo'<embed src="valentine.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" hidden="true" ></embed>';
```

but no result. **Please help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  [HTMl5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

```
 <audio src="audio.mp3" preload="auto" controls autoplay loop></audio>
```

The preload attribute is used in the audio element for buffering large files. It can take one of 3 values:

1. "none" does not buffer the file
2. "auto" buffers the media file
3. "metadata" buffers only the metadata for the file

Comment: This only works for browsers that support MP3.  You must support other codecs as well.

Comment: Thanks friend. I use your way but the song don't autosart.

Comment: @user3274646 i added auto play option